# Customize Wordpress Core Template

Tags: pagination

I used the `paginate_links()` function to retrieve pagination and everything works fine. It returns every link as `a` anchor tag it is also fine if we want links inside `<li></li>` we can specify return type as `array` and then loop to add links to `<li></li>`.

but what is the solution for current page link it return a span tag but i want wordpress to give me an anchor tag with `href="#"` attribute. i google but not find any solution instead i get understand from where this template is generating it's located in `general-template.php` file and it's easy to just replace html template there and that's it.

but it is not permanent solution nor good wordpress development.

**cons of doing so**

1) whenever wordpress will update my changes will lost.
2) it's not effective in just my theme it will disturb core template

anyone can help me out what is the better way to do so..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it isn't pluggable, you could define a replacement function in your theme. In your theme's `functions.php` file, copy the core `paginate_links()` function, rename the function - perhaps `my_paginate_links()`, modify the source code so it creates the anchor tag you need, and then call your new function wherever you need it in the rest of the theme.